# jquery UI date picker clone overlapping years how to calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

With my current code I was able to do the year of experience caluclation how to check overlapping dates. For example if user select from the original div
19/5/2005 - 18/6/2015 once the user click the add more button in the cloned div if user select 19/3/2003 - 18/6/2016. It should say an alert message.

Here is the jquery code

```
/* select exp date ends here*/
/* dates starts here*/

/*addmore functionalities starts here*/
   /*dynamic row for Education Table starts here*/
    var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".edu_add_button", function () {            
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row1:eq(0)').clone(true,true);
        //alert("Clone number" + clone);
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 edu_btnle' id='buttonless'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        $clone.find(".school_Name").attr('disabled', true).val('');
        $clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');
        $clone.find("input.deg_date")
          .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
          .removeData('datepicker')
          .unbind()
          .datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showButtonPanel: false,
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $clone.find("input.trans_date")
          .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
          .removeData('datepicker')
          .unbind()
          .datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showButtonPanel: false,
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(this).parents('.educat_info').after($clone);
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
        var len = $('.cloned-row1').length;
        if(len>1){
            $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }
    });
    /*dynamic row for Education Table ends here*/
    /*dynamic row for Test Score Table starts here*/
    var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".test_add_button", function () {           
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row2:eq(0)').clone(true,true);
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 selbtnless' id='buttonless'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        /*$clone.find(".school_Name").attr('disabled', true).val('');
        $clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');*/
        $clone.find("input.txt_date")
          .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
          .removeData('datepicker')
          .unbind()
          .datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showButtonPanel: false,
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(this).parents('.sel_text').after($clone);
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
        var len = $('.cloned-row2').length;
        if(len>1){
            $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }
    });
    /*dynamic row for Test Score Table ends here*/
    /*dynamic row for Work Experience Table starts here*/
    var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".exp_add_button", function () {                
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row3:eq(0)').clone(true,true);
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1 selbtnless' id='buttonless'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        $clone.find(".startDate").val('');
        $clone.find(".endDate").val('');
        /*$clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');*/
        $clone.find("input.startDate")
          .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
          .removeData('datepicker')
          .unbind()
          .datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showButtonPanel: false,
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $clone.find("input.endDate")
          .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
          .removeData('datepicker')
          .unbind()
          .datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            showButtonPanel: false,
            beforeShow: function () {
                setTimeout(function (){
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

                }, 0);
            }
        });
        $(this).parents('.wrk_exp').after($clone);
    });
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bqgjro6d/)

Kindly please suggest me.

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the dates

```
$.each($(dateStart),function(key,value)
```

you are capturing the dates and differences, but you are not comparing the previous from date

```
if(dateStart[key-1])
```

the above code will help you to get the previous rows values using key-1 and you can compare the dates

Please refer the fiddle URL http://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/bqgjro6d/7/
date format is MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: thanks for the help but i am not getting any alert :(

Comment: press tab in last box after filling it

Comment: more over the calculation also was not happening :(

Comment: type date with hyphens 10-10-2005, 10-10-2015, 10-10-2003, 10-10-2016 these 4 dates you try

Comment: hi overlapping working fine but year calculation was not working kindly please help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90097/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-zigma-empire).